# Android: How To Fix TextView side by side?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a problem with "TextView" I do not know how to solve. I have three "TextView" within a "LinearLayout" and that the texts would stay the same size, same as break line. At the moment, the texts are on the same line, but with different sizes. What to do? The following image and code:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/complementaryInfoLayout"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@color/purewhite">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textCategory"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="#545454"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"               
                android:text="@string/placeholder" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textCity"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="#545454"
                android:text="@string/placeholder" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textNeighborhood"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="#545454"
                android:text="@string/placeholder" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

[How is the tablet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bO0dR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Well.. The last line seems to be breaking duo the string size. 
You may obligate TextView occupy one line regardless its content by using:

`android:singleLine="true"`

Furthermore you can give a nice touch by using:

`android:ellipsize="marquee"`

So it wont crop abruptly the content in it.

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

Try giving weights to your `TextView`s :

```
        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/complementaryInfoLayout"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@color/purewhite">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textCategory"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#545454"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"               
            android:text="@string/placeholder" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textCity"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#545454"
            android:text="@string/placeholder" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textNeighborhood"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#545454"
            android:text="@string/placeholder" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

need some clarity on your query, i hope you want to adjust three childs in linear layout horizontally, for this

you can use `android:layout_weight`  attribute, in below code i have used `layout_weight` as `2, 3 and 5`  respectiviely,

here `2+3+5=10` i.e `total 10 parts equal to 100% width`

so first textview occupies `(2/10)*100 = 20% width` horiontally

so second textview occupies `(3/10)*100 = 30%` width horiontally

so third textview occupies `(5/10)*100 = 50% width` horiontally

```
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/complementaryInfoLayout"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:background="@color/purewhite">
              <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textCategory"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
             <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textCity"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
             <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textNeighborhood"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```